# How does assuming multiple IAM roles at the same time work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an ECS task using a task role to access a DynamoDB table in the same account A. It also requires access to a DynamoDB table in a different account B, which is granted through assuming an IAM role.

My understanding is that after assuming the role, the task now has a set of temporary credentials for each role. This allows the task to use the new credentials to make requests to account B's table, while still using the original credentials to make requests to account A's table.

Assuming this is correct, how are the creds used for a given request determined? Does it only use the cross account role for making account B requests, and the original creds for the account A requests?

What if access to account B S3 buckets are also required and the permissions were granted to account A, which were then given to original task role? After assuming the cross account role, does the cross account S3 request fail because the assumed role doesn't have S3 permissions, even though the original take role does?

Comment: Just to simplyfy - assuming roles means switching a set of credentials, not extending them. So assuming a new role the client is giving up the current one. The new role must have all permissions that the client needs.

Answer (score 0):

AWS resources cannot just assume a role themselves. They have to be told to do so, and use the SDK of your choice to do so (or the CLI). Soon as you understand how that works it becomes a lot more clear how this works. Since you mentioned and ec2 instance, I'll use the CLI to show this

```
AcctCredentials=($(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$1" --role-session-name TheSessionName --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]' --output text))
unset AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
echo "Security Tokens for Cross Account Access received"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AcctCredentials[0]}
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AcctCredentials[1]}
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AcctCredentials[2]}
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=${AcctCredentials[2]}
```

doing that you are setting your env variables in the ec2 to these new credentials. This means any other CLI commands run or any script that is launched from the same shell as this one will use these credentials.

If you need to go back to the credentials from before, you will either need to reset/save your credentials from before or exit the shell this command was run in and return to your default credentials.

If this was in a lambda for instance however, you might be using Python and the Boto3 to do something very similar. It would replace the tokens there.

It is also entirely possible to save your tokens as a Profile that the commands can use, and then per command specify the profile you are using for that command.

Comment: You are right, using profiles will allow to switch roles nicely https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/never-put-aws-temporary-credentials-in-env-vars-or-credentials-files-theres-a-better-way-25ec45b4d73e

Comment: But If I have a lot of assume roles or profile. It is not easy for me to remember all of it. It is pretty hard for me if MFA is required every time I assume role. I already create a repo to make it easy. You can search and assume role which you want to use or switch. It will cache your credentials and you can re-use before It is expired - github.com/lamhaison/aws-cli-utils